# Return Image using IHttpActionResult

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have a requirement to return an image from a WebApi using IHttpActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage. How this can be achieved &  what are the accept & content type headers need to be passed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

I was actually looking for a solution to send an image resides on internet from web api but I am returning local thumbnail images from my web api with the following code;

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("thumbnail/{userId}/{fileName}")]
public IHttpActionResult GetThumbnail()
{
        var mediaRoot = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/media");

        var imgPath = Path.Combine(mediaRoot, "images", userId, "thumbnail", fileName);
        var fileInfo = new FileInfo(imgPath);

        return !fileInfo.Exists
            ? (IHttpActionResult)NotFound()
            : new FileResult(fileInfo.FullName);
}
```

Hope this helps

**Edit: You should create a custom IHttpActionResult to retun images,**

It seems i have created a custom IHttpActionResult to return images and here is the post that i got this code from > [Custom IHttpActionResult](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23768883/1310708)

Answer (score 0):

This would be a basic way:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public IHttpActionResult GetImageTest()
{
    var stream = File.OpenRead(@"C:\picture.jpg");

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);

    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;

    return ResponseMessage(response);
}
```